# Differentiability question wouldn't $f(0,0)$ be undefined because

Tags: calculus

Hi i was given a set of solutions i couldn't and got stuck at this part. Please My question is not the given question but rather the given solution.

I know that differentiability is to show that

$$\lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{f(a+h,b+h)+f(a,b)}{h} $$

But the question is....
[image]

And then i'm told.... 
[image]

Which is to what i figured

But then there is this part...
[image]

> wouldn't $f(0,0)$ be inconsistent? Also why "$0+t$" alternate between the two is it because all of y is zero along the path of x and vice versa for y? Why are we using the differentiability of each derivative?

Comment: (1) Your definition of differentiability is wrong. (2) The questions at the end are really unclear. What is inconsistent about $f(0,0)$? It is defined as $0$. (3) What alternates? The entire question part of your question is using imprecise terminology, and it is unclear what you are talking about, but it probably all stems from your misunderstanding of differentiability of functions of two variables.

Comment: Away from the origin there is no concern, you can zoom in on a region which doesn't contain the origin, and then you don't see anything weird happening. At the origin, the partial derivative with respect to $x$ is defined to be $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}$ and the partial derivative with respect to $y$ is defined to be $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0,h)-f(0,0)}{h}$. So can you clarify where your difficulty is? Perhaps it is in understanding what it means for the function as a whole to not be differentiable at the origin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key error you've made is the definition of differentiability.

A function of two real variable $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ if there are real numbers $u,v$, such that:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)} \frac{f(x,y)-f(a,b)-u(x-a)-v(y-b)}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}} = 0$$

This can be read as saying, roughly:

> $f(x,y)$ can be approximated well near $(a,b)$ as $$f(x,y)\approx f(a,b)+u(x-a)+v(y-b)$$

The denominator $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}$ indicates how good this approximation must be when we are near $(a,b)$. In particular, if $f$ is differentiable, then $u,v$ are distinct - there is at most one pair $(u,v)$ which matches this condition.

In all cases, if there is a pair $u,v$ then $$u=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b), v=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b)$$

But the point of this exercise/discussion is to show that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b)$ can exist and still not have $f$ differentiable at $(0,0)$.

In this particular case, $(a,b)=(0,0)$ and $f(x,y)=\frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2}$ and you can show that if $(u,v)$ exists, they must be the partial derivatives, $(u,v)=(1,-1)$ This yields, when $(x,y)\neq 0$:

$$\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-ux-vy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{xy(y-x)}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$

If $y=2x$ then we get:

$$\frac{xy(y-x)}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{2x^3}{|x|^3\cdot 5^{3/2}}=\pm \frac{2}{5^{3/2}}$$

So the left side does not converge to $0$ as $(x,y)\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

What is the definition of partial derivative of a map? Recall that a partial derivative of a map is a special case of the directional derivative of the map in the direction of a usual standard unit vector; this is why you see "alternation".

If $f$ is differentiable at some $a \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, *i.e.* if the derivative $df^{a}: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ of $f$ at $a$ exists, then we have
$$
f'(a; y) = df^{a}(y)
$$
for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$.
Using this theorem, let us see if $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$. If $y = (y_{1},y_{2}) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $y_{1} \neq y_{2}$, then 
$$
h^{-1}\big[f(hy_{1},hy_{2}) - f(0,0) \big]= h^{-1}\frac{y_{1}^{3} - y_{2}^{3}}{y_{1}^{3} + y_{2}^{3}}
$$
for all $h \neq 0$, so $f'((0,0);y)$ does not exist, and hence $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.